# Used CloudFormation to create Wordpress blog but domain doesn't show up properly

Tags: wordpress, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, dns, aws-cloudformation

I used *AWS CloudFormation* to create a Wordpress blog and then bought a domain from GoDaddy website and forwarded it to the domain name provided by CloudFormation

-->*godaddy domain*: yetanotherdeveloper.in

-->*cloudformation domain:* "ec2-35-154-134-194.ap-south-1.compute.amazonaws.com/wordpress/"

**Problem 1:**
When I search GoDaddy domain in the URL, I get to the site but then only CloudFormation domain is shown in the URL. I want the GoDaddy domain to be there.
When I open a post, before the slash in the URL, *cloudformation* domain is shown.(*e.g.* `ec2-35-154-134-194.ap-south-1.compute.amazonaws.com/wordpress/index.php**/2017/09/27/hello-world/**`) .I want *godaddy* domain to be there for ease of access for others.

**Problem 2:**
Cloudformation uses a public IP which could be dangerous in future in case the server gets down etc. So, i want to change the IP to elastic IP too.

[This is after the site is loaded,i get old domain shown](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HInTJ.png)

[This is when i open some other page or in this case, a post. Here also old domain](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Q2jcs.png)

one last thing, i hope i'm not wasting much time of yours. If i am, it would be great to point out what i did wrong in this question and i will improve next time.

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Regarding the URL, you need to set the root URL on the WordPress configuration to http://yetanotherdeveloper.in, and regarding Elastic IP, you need to update the Cloudformation template to create an EIP and link it to the created instance.
Best regards.

Answer (score 0):

You will likely need to [change your site URL](https://codex.wordpress.org/Changing_The_Site_URL) in the WordPress configuration:

> On the Settings->General screen in a single site installation of
>   WordPress, there are two fields named "WordPress Address (URL)" and
>   "Site Address (URL)". They are important settings, since they control
>   where WordPress thinks your site is located. They control the display
>   of the URL in the admin section of your page, as well as the front
>   end, and are used throughout the WordPress code.